# Passing a variable into a JSON-value-request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I consider myself to be at somewhat of an intermediate level in Javasript, but I am hitting a major roadblock in trying to access the key (in the key/value pair) of a JSON message that is returned back.

I am writing my code in such a way that the exact key is not static, so it needs to be passed into the JSON-return-message query. For example:

After running the following JSON query:

```
    var wizards = JSON.parse([some url]);
```

I get the following data returned back (I formatted it myself to look readable):

```
    {
    "Status":"Success",
    "IsValidSession":"False",
    "ErrorMessage":"Success",
    "CUSTOM_MARKER_ID_FROM_DCVIEW1":
    [
        {
            "PlaceID":"CUSTOM_MARKER_ID_FROM_DCVIEW",
            "IsVisible":"true",
            "Message":"An e-stop has been pulled.",
            "ImageName":"alert.png",
            "IsPulse":"No"
        }
    ]
    }
```

"CUSTOM_MARKER_ID_FROM_DCVIEW1" is what needs to be variable based when I query "wizards". I cannot simply just hard-code it in:

```
    $.each(wizards.CUSTOM_MARKER_ID_FROM_DCVIEW1, function(j, jValue) {/*do some stuff*/});
```

Is there a way to pass in a variable after "wizards."??

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the square-bracket notation:

```
var key = "CUSTOM_MARKER_ID_FROM_DCVIEW1";
$.each(wizards[key], function() {  ...  } );
```